# Can't connect to solana devnet using solana cli or curl

Tags: jsonrpc-api, devnet

All things are ok when I use localhost.But when I change to devnet, I cannot develop programs(solana balance/airdrop are ok).

```
RPC URL: https://api.devnet.solana.com
Default Signer Path: /Users/chenyu/.config/solana/id.json
Commitment: confirmed
thread 'main' panicked at cli/src/program.rs:2188:26:
Should return a valid tpu client: PubsubError(ConnectionError(Io(Os { code: 60, kind: TimedOut, message: "Operation timed out" })))
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Using cURL to send a request also doesn't work, but using Postman is ok.

```
$ curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"getFees"}' -v

* Host api.devnet.solana.com:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: 2001::6ca0:a62a
* IPv4: 162.125.32.13
*   Trying 162.125.32.13:443...
* connect to 162.125.32.13 port 443 from 192.168.1.6 port 53405 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying [2001::6ca0:a62a]:443...
* connect to 2001::6ca0:a62a port 443 from 2409:8a55:3116:ee90:29c8:9006:b478:bf4d port 53406 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to api.devnet.solana.com port 443 after 75023 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection
curl: (28) Failed to connect to api.devnet.solana.com port 443 after 75023 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get this error also when you try mainnet and/or testnet?

Comment: I get the same error using curl on testnet and mainnet. My account has insufficient funds on testnet and mainnet .